# Do I `HAVE` to add a space inside an empty DIV tag?

Tags: html, space

I was reading a book about AJAX and the writer said that one should always add a space inside of empty div tags so as to not risk compatibility problems in "some browsers".

So this would be wrong `<div></div>` and this would be right `<div> </div>`.

Question: Is he an idiot or does he know something?

Thank you.

Comment: @chigley, putting additional characters all over the place for no reason is a problem.

Comment: @chigley that seems like a very cargo-cult mentality. "I heard it might help, and it doesn't hurt to include it so I'll just do that without question."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

He's not an idiot.  IE 8 (possibly earlier versions as well?) will subtly mess up your layout if your empty div is really empty; adding a comment seems to be the suggested way of dealing with it, but apparently a space works as well.

Comment: +1 I find using a comment weirder than using a space, because a comment isn't supposed to influence *anything* whereas a space character is still text, somehow. Then again, that's the way IE is — always the quirky odd one out.

Comment: Wooble: That doesn't mean he's not an idiot, it just means saying what he said doesn't prove it. :D

Comment: Either I haven't used a lot of empty divs so far, or I haven't noticed any such subtle problems. Could you please give an example of when this may mess things up?

Comment: I think that if you use a div as a spacer (for example) setting its height and width to say 20px (`<div style="width:20px;height:20px;"></div>`) it doesn't always render so in some versions of IE unless you add a space or comment as indicated in the answers here inside the div.

Answer (score 1):

i usually add `&nbsp;` instead of the empty space!

Answer (score 1):

I would add a comment so that nothing is displayed. This does cause problems in ie8 for some reason!